Interpolation of Lebesgue and Holder spaces
Im interested in the interpolation by complex and real methods between lebesgue $L^p$ spaces and $C^{0,\mu}$ Holder continuous spaces, in particular the interpolation of the pair $(L^p(\mathbb{R}^n,C^{0,1-n/p}(\mathbb{R}^n))$. I think this could be a particular case of interpolation of Morrey-Campanato spaces, however all the information i found about those spaces concern only to bounded domains $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, and I'm interested in the spaces defined in the whole space. Any reference or idea? Thanks in advance
